# VB.net Socket Response String is getting cut

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I have this code, and it connects properly to the server socket, authenticates and subscribes. but the server response is being cut at 243 chars so the JSON parser throws an error of unhandled data because the string is not complete. Any ideas will be much appreciated.. Weird thing is that I have a C# version exactly the same, I translated from C# to VB.net, and the C# version pulls the full string with no issues... I think it has something to do with the buffer size, but Im not really sure

```
Public Sub Run()
        Try
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting...")
            Dim client As New TcpClient("xxxxxxxx", xxxxx)
            client.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 64 * 1024 * 1024
            client.ReceiveBufferSize = 64 * 1024 * 1024

            Dim ns As NetworkStream = client.GetStream

            SendMessage(ns, "{""r"":""authenticate"",""a"":{""key"":""xxxxxxxxxx""}}")
            SendMessage(ns, "{""r"":""subscribe_events"",""a"":{ ""sport_id"":"""", ""changes_after"":""2022-11-11T00:00:00Z""}}")
            ReceiveAsync(client)
            Console.WriteLine("Connected...")
            receiveCompleted.WaitOne()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error")
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Sub SendMessage(ByVal ns As NetworkStream, ByVal stringData As String)
        Dim length As Integer = stringData.Length
        'Dim headBuffer As New Byte()
        Dim headBuffer = New Byte(3) {CByte(length >> 24), CByte(length >> 16), CByte(length >> 8), CByte(length)}

        ns.Write(headBuffer, 0, headBuffer.Length)
        ns.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringData), 0, stringData.Length)
    End Sub
    Private Sub ReceiveAsync(ByVal client As TcpClient)
        Try
            Dim state As StateObject = New StateObject()
            state.workSocket = client
            state.bufSize = 4
            state.remainedSize = 4
            client.Client.BeginReceive(state.buffer_size2, 0, 4, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback_size), state)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error")
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Started")
        _runner = New Thread(AddressOf Run)
        _runner.Start()
        'Run()
        'Console.Read()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReceiveCallback_size(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        'Try
        Dim state As StateObject = CType(ar.AsyncState, StateObject)
            Dim client = state.workSocket
            Dim byteRead As Integer = client.Client.EndReceive(ar)

            If byteRead > 0 Then
                state.remainedSize -= byteRead

                If state.remainedSize > 0 Then
                    client.Client.BeginReceive(state.buffer_size2, state.bufSize - state.remainedSize, state.remainedSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback_size), state)
                Else
                    Dim bodySize As Integer = state.buffer_size2(3) Or (state.buffer_size2(2) << 8) Or (state.buffer_size2(1) << 16) Or (state.buffer_size2(0) << 24)
                    state.buffer = New Byte(bodySize - 1) {}
                    state.bufSize = bodySize
                    state.remainedSize = bodySize
                    client.Client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, bodySize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback_data), state)
                End If
            Else
                receiveCompleted.[Set]()
            End If

        'Catch e As Exception
        '    Console.WriteLine("Error")
        '    Console.WriteLine(e)
        'End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub ReceiveCallback_data(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        'Try
        Dim state As StateObject = CType(ar.AsyncState, StateObject)
            Dim client = state.workSocket
            Dim byteRead As Integer = client.Client.EndReceive(ar)

            If byteRead > 0 Then
                state.remainedSize -= byteRead

                If state.remainedSize > 0 Then
                client.Client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, state.bufSize - state.remainedSize, state.remainedSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback_data), state)
            Else
                    Dim strData As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, state.bufSize)
                    NewData(strData)
                    state.bufSize = 4
                    state.remainedSize = 4
                    client.Client.BeginReceive(state.buffer_size2, 0, 4, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback_size), state)
                End If
            Else
                receiveCompleted.[Set]()
            End If

        'Catch ex As Exception
        '    Console.WriteLine("Error")
        '    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        'End Try
    End Sub
    Public Sub NewData(ByVal strJson As String)
        'If strJson.Length > 200 Then
        '    listBox1.Items.Insert(0, strJson.Substring(0, 200))
        'Else
        '    listBox1.Items.Insert(0, strJson)
        'End If
        Console.WriteLine(strJson)
        Dim data As JObject = JObject.Parse(strJson)
        lastMessageTime = data("dt").Value(Of String)()

        If data("r").Value(Of String)() = "event" Then

            Try
                handleMatchData(data)
            Catch e As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(strJson)
                Console.WriteLine(e)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

Public Class StateObject
        Public workSocket As TcpClient = Nothing
        Public Const BUFFER_SIZE As Integer = 64 * 1024 * 1024
        Public buffer As Byte()
        Public buffer_size2 As Byte() = New Byte(3) {}
        Public sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        Public bufSize As Integer = 0
        Public remainedSize As Integer = 0
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SendMessage()` method is sending a 4-byte integer representing `stringData`'s length before then sending `stringData` itself.  That is a good design choice when sending messages over a TCP connection.

However, the length you are sending (as well as passing to `Write()` ) is the *character count* of `stringData`, not the *byte count* of `stringData` after it has been encoded to UTF-8.  `ReceiveCallback_data()` (and `Write()`) is expecting a *byte count*, not a *character count*.  They are not the same thing, unless you are sending purely ASCII characters only.  If you send any non-ASCII characters, your code will not work correctly.

You should encode `stringData` to UTF-8 first, THEN use the size of its encoded bytes.  That way, the receiver can read in the byte count first, then read in the specified number of bytes, then decode the bytes as UTF-8 (you are *encoding* as UTF-8 but *decoding* as ASCII).

Try something more like this instead:

```vb
Public Sub SendMessage(ByVal ns As NetworkStream, ByVal stringData As String)
    Dim stringBytes as Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringData);
    Dim length As Integer = stringBytes.Length
    Dim lengthBytes = New Byte(3) {CByte(length >> 24), CByte(length >> 16), CByte(length >> 8), CByte(length)}

    ns.Write(lengthBytes, 0, lengthBytes.Length)
    ns.Write(stringBytes, 0, stringBytes.Length)
End Sub

Private Sub ReceiveAsync(ByVal client As TcpClient)
    Try
        Dim state As StateObject = New StateObject()
        state.workSocket = client
        state.expectedSize = 4
        state.remainingSize = 4
        client.Client.BeginReceive(state.buffer_size, 0, 4, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback_size), state)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error")
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ReceiveCallback_size(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    'Try
        Dim state As StateObject = CType(ar.AsyncState, StateObject)
        Dim client = state.workSocket
        Dim byteRead As Integer = client.Client.EndReceive(ar)

        If byteRead > 0 Then
            state.remainingSize -= byteRead
            If state.remainingSize > 0 Then
                client.Client.BeginReceive(state.buffer_size, state.expectedSize - state.remainingSize, state.remainingSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback_size), state)
            Else
                Dim bodySize As Integer = state.buffer_size(3) Or (state.buffer_size(2) << 8) Or (state.buffer_size(1) << 16) Or (state.buffer_size(0) << 24)
                If bodySize > 0 Then
                    state.buffer_data = New Byte(bodySize - 1)
                    state.expectedSize = bodySize
                    state.remainingSize = bodySize
                    client.Client.BeginReceive(state.buffer_data, 0, bodySize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback_data), state)
                Else
                    'NewData("")
                    ReceiveAsync(client)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            receiveCompleted.[Set]()
        End If

    'Catch e As Exception
    '    Console.WriteLine("Error")
    '    Console.WriteLine(e)
    'End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ReceiveCallback_data(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    'Try
        Dim state As StateObject = CType(ar.AsyncState, StateObject)
        Dim client = state.workSocket
        Dim byteRead As Integer = client.Client.EndReceive(ar)

        If byteRead > 0 Then
            state.remainingSize -= byteRead
            If state.remainingSize > 0 Then
                client.Client.BeginReceive(state.buffer_data, state.expectedSize - state.remainingSize, state.remainingSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback_data), state)
            Else
                Dim strData As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer_data, 0, state.expectedSize)
                NewData(strData)
                ReceiveAsync(client)
            End If
        Else
            receiveCompleted.[Set]()
        End If

    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    Console.WriteLine("Error")
    '    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    'End Try
End Sub

Public Class StateObject
    Public workSocket As TcpClient = Nothing
    Public buffer_size As Byte() = New Byte(3)
    Public buffer_data As Byte()
    Public expectedSize As Integer = 0
    Public remainingSize As Integer = 0
End Class
```